# Sum root term's entries count from child terms count

Tags: menus, terms

I have nested terms menu in this structure:

- Root term (0)

  - Sub term (1)

    - SubSub term (5)

The root term doesnt have any posts related to it and the count shows 0 correctly, but in the Navigation menu I want to show a sum of all the sub-terms count since the menu is expandable. the structure should look like this:

- Root term (6)

  - Sub term (1)

    - SubSub term (5)

How can I achieve this via wordpress on `wp_list_categories` without really affecting the db values but just for the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php 

    $children = get_term_children( $parent_term, $taxonomy );

    $child_count = count($children);

?>
```

Comment: Updated my question, this should be used inside `wp_list_categories`